# Package and footprint - Are they correct

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, footprint, packages

In this [device](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf), on page 208, the page has the Package outline drawing. 8-pin package. SOIC.

"8S2, 8-lead, 0.208” Body, Plastic Small
Outline Package (EIAJ)"

I want the footprint of this device.

Hence, I checked this [PDF](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/PackagingSpec/00000049BN%20.pdf), which has the packages and footprints.

While searching for the footprint in the second pdf, I couldn't find a 8-pin SOIC footprint. However, there was 8-pin SOIJ package. You can find the footprint on page 162 on the second PDF.

My question is, whether the land pattern/footprint on the second pdf is the right one for the package mentioned in the 208 page of the first pdf?

Comment: It's not the same package, but probably close enough.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, can I use it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR;** In this particular case, the Microchip footprint you found looks perfectly reasonable for the Atmel part.

---

Bear in mind that Atmel was acquired by Microchip, so it's not suprising that the Microchip document doesn't contain footprints for ex-Atmel parts.

Simply looking at the dimensions of both you can check to see if the footprint is suitable. Critical dimensions include:

- Pitch - must match exactly
- Pad Spacing - whole of pin must sit fully on each pad
- Pad Width - must be greater or equal to the max pin width

For large packages like SOIC, you can take quite a lot of liberties with the dimensions, so as long as the footprint is vaguely similar you will be fine.

For completeness, with tiny packages (e.g. TSSOP), leadless packages (e.g. QFN), ball and land grid parts (e.g. BGA), and other small parts you need to be more careful. Ideally using the manufacturers recommendations if they exist, or best judgement otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think, I can use the footprint for the Atmel SOIC part?

Comment: @Freshman yes, it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and confirmation Tom. Much appreciate it. Accepting the answer now